# ListView in flutter implement with json data

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

This is my json string and I want to know how to use it

```html
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Data Received successful",
    "data": [
         {
            "billing_address": "BAGHPAT , BAGHPAT , UTTAR PRADESH - 250609",
            "delivery_address": "",
            "order_input": "0",
            "order_no": "Packaging BAWANA121020200001",
            "status": "Pending",
            "order_date": "12-10-2020",
            "order_time": "08:13:53",
            "total_quantity": 5,
            "gst": "09AUIOP",
            "shipp_address": null,
            "shipp_city": null,
            "shipp_state": null,
            "shipp_pincode": null,
            "shipp_mobile": null,
            "shipp_name": null,
            "bill_date": null,
            "challan": "",
            "bill": "",
            "expexted_deliverd_date": "19-10-2020"
        },

  ]
}
```

This is my json and I want to it to call inside ListView in Flutter

I have tried many things in Internet But anything does not work inside this flutter image and I want to call this Json. Please suggest me tutorial that is same like this Json

Comment: create a model representing the json fields

Comment: Have you any Tutorial or link through which i can do that

Comment: https://bezkoder.com/dart-flutter-convert-object-to-json-string/ See this tut

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Get Model for any response by simply pasting you response into [here](https://app.quicktype.io)

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Model> modelFromJson(String str) => List<Model>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Model.fromJson(x)));

String modelToJson(List<Model> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Model {
    Model({
        this.billingAddress,
        this.deliveryAddress,
        this.orderInput,
        this.orderNo,
        this.status,
        this.orderDate,
        this.orderTime,
        this.totalQuantity,
        this.gst,
        this.shippAddress,
        this.shippCity,
        this.shippState,
        this.shippPincode,
        this.shippMobile,
        this.shippName,
        this.billDate,
        this.challan,
        this.bill,
        this.expextedDeliverdDate,
    });

    final String billingAddress;
    final String deliveryAddress;
    final String orderInput;
    final String orderNo;
    final String status;
    final String orderDate;
    final String orderTime;
    final int totalQuantity;
    final String gst;
    final dynamic shippAddress;
    final dynamic shippCity;
    final dynamic shippState;
    final dynamic shippPincode;
    final dynamic shippMobile;
    final dynamic shippName;
    final dynamic billDate;
    final String challan;
    final String bill;
    final String expextedDeliverdDate;

    factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Model(
        billingAddress: json["billing_address"],
        deliveryAddress: json["delivery_address"],
        orderInput: json["order_input"],
        orderNo: json["order_no"],
        status: json["status"],
        orderDate: json["order_date"],
        orderTime: json["order_time"],
        totalQuantity: json["total_quantity"],
        gst: json["gst"],
        shippAddress: json["shipp_address"],
        shippCity: json["shipp_city"],
        shippState: json["shipp_state"],
        shippPincode: json["shipp_pincode"],
        shippMobile: json["shipp_mobile"],
        shippName: json["shipp_name"],
        billDate: json["bill_date"],
        challan: json["challan"],
        bill: json["bill"],
        expextedDeliverdDate: json["expexted_deliverd_date"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "billing_address": billingAddress,
        "delivery_address": deliveryAddress,
        "order_input": orderInput,
        "order_no": orderNo,
        "status": status,
        "order_date": orderDate,
        "order_time": orderTime,
        "total_quantity": totalQuantity,
        "gst": gst,
        "shipp_address": shippAddress,
        "shipp_city": shippCity,
        "shipp_state": shippState,
        "shipp_pincode": shippPincode,
        "shipp_mobile": shippMobile,
        "shipp_name": shippName,
        "bill_date": billDate,
        "challan": challan,
        "bill": bill,
        "expexted_deliverd_date": expextedDeliverdDate,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic example to parse your json file that you provided.

Below is your json file :

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Data Received successful",
    "data": [
         {
            "billing_address": "BAGHPAT , BAGHPAT , UTTAR PRADESH - 250609",
            "delivery_address": "",
            "order_input": "0",
            "order_no": "Packaging BAWANA121020200001",
            "status": "Pending",
            "order_date": "12-10-2020",
            "order_time": "08:13:53",
            "total_quantity": 5,
            "gst": "09AUIOP",
            "shipp_address": null,
            "shipp_city": null,
            "shipp_state": null,
            "shipp_pincode": null,
            "shipp_mobile": null,
            "shipp_name": null,
            "bill_date": null,
            "challan": "",
            "bill": "",
            "expexted_deliverd_date": "19-10-2020"
        }

  ]
}
```

Below is the model that I have created for the json that you provided.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final model = modelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Model modelFromJson(String str) => Model.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String modelToJson(Model data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Model {
    Model({
        this.status,
        this.message,
        this.data,
    });

    int status;
    String message;
    List<Datum> data;

    factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Model(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        this.billingAddress,
        this.deliveryAddress,
        this.orderInput,
        this.orderNo,
        this.status,
        this.orderDate,
        this.orderTime,
        this.totalQuantity,
        this.gst,
        this.shippAddress,
        this.shippCity,
        this.shippState,
        this.shippPincode,
        this.shippMobile,
        this.shippName,
        this.billDate,
        this.challan,
        this.bill,
        this.expextedDeliverdDate,
    });

    String billingAddress;
    String deliveryAddress;
    String orderInput;
    String orderNo;
    String status;
    String orderDate;
    String orderTime;
    int totalQuantity;
    String gst;
    dynamic shippAddress;
    dynamic shippCity;
    dynamic shippState;
    dynamic shippPincode;
    dynamic shippMobile;
    dynamic shippName;
    dynamic billDate;
    String challan;
    String bill;
    String expextedDeliverdDate;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        billingAddress: json["billing_address"],
        deliveryAddress: json["delivery_address"],
        orderInput: json["order_input"],
        orderNo: json["order_no"],
        status: json["status"],
        orderDate: json["order_date"],
        orderTime: json["order_time"],
        totalQuantity: json["total_quantity"],
        gst: json["gst"],
        shippAddress: json["shipp_address"],
        shippCity: json["shipp_city"],
        shippState: json["shipp_state"],
        shippPincode: json["shipp_pincode"],
        shippMobile: json["shipp_mobile"],
        shippName: json["shipp_name"],
        billDate: json["bill_date"],
        challan: json["challan"],
        bill: json["bill"],
        expextedDeliverdDate: json["expexted_deliverd_date"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "billing_address": billingAddress,
        "delivery_address": deliveryAddress,
        "order_input": orderInput,
        "order_no": orderNo,
        "status": status,
        "order_date": orderDate,
        "order_time": orderTime,
        "total_quantity": totalQuantity,
        "gst": gst,
        "shipp_address": shippAddress,
        "shipp_city": shippCity,
        "shipp_state": shippState,
        "shipp_pincode": shippPincode,
        "shipp_mobile": shippMobile,
        "shipp_name": shippName,
        "bill_date": billDate,
        "challan": challan,
        "bill": bill,
        "expexted_deliverd_date": expextedDeliverdDate,
    };
}
```

Based on the model generated I have integrated json data into the ui :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'package:json_parsing_example/model2.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _isLoading = false;

  List<Datum> usersList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    final model = modelFromJson(data);

    usersList = model.data;

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Users List "),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: usersList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var item = usersList[index];
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(item.billingAddress),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(item.orderNo),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(item.expextedDeliverdDate),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
    ));
  }
}
```

This is the sample Example that I have provided you can use the complex ways using the MVVM with provider or using the bloc, Its on you.
I have Mentioned some articles and tuts do check it out.
https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wc8ecFSu5N8